# MySql Form query for filters or Ignore WHERE clause for column value in NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm trying to fetch a user list where gender, region, and status are the mandatory filters in my app. Filtering works fine when gender is either 0 or 1. The problem is when I need both. Scenario is same for all 3 filters.

API: `https://website.com/api/getUsers?gender=0&region=1&status=1` to get filter results.

**APPROACH 1:** I want to pass something for those api params for eg. gender=#$%, so that it ignores its WHERE clause when passing it on queryInputs below.

```
module.exports.getMatches = ({offset, gender, status, region}, callback) => {
var dbQuery = 'SELECT * from `users` WHERE `gender` = ? AND `status` = ? AND `region` = ? LIMIT ? OFFSET ?';
var queryInputs = [parseInt(gender), parseInt(status), parseInt(region), 10, parseInt(offset)];

db.query(dbQuery, queryInputs, function(err, result) {
    //code goes here
});
}
```

**APPROACH 2:** I'm passing empty params to validate to fetch all data for particular filters for eg. `https://website.com/api/getUsers?gender=&region=1&status=`

I'm trying to avoid WHERE clause if I pass empty params in api. This almost worked for me if it weren't for last AND before LIMIT in the query.

```
module.exports.getMatches = ({offset, gender, status, region}, callback) => {
var dbQuery = 'SELECT * from `users`';
if( gender != '' || status!= '' || region != '') dbQuery += ' WHERE'
if(gender != ''){
    dbQuery += ' `gender` = '+ db.escape(parseInt(gender))+' AND';
}
if(status != ''){
    dbQuery += ' `status` = '+ db.escape(parseInt(status))+' AND';
}
if(region != ''){
    dbQuery += ' `region` = '+ db.escape(parseInt(region))+' AND';
}
dbQuery += ' LIMIT 10 OFFSET ' + db.escape(parseInt(offset));

db.query(dbQuery, queryInputs, function(err, result) {
    //code goes here
});
}
```

Among these two Approches solution for anyone works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an edit for your second approach. This should allow you to put "AND" before your query additions so you avoid your stated error.

```
module.exports.getMatches = ({offset, gender, status, region}, callback) => {
var dbQuery = 'SELECT * from `users` WHERE 1=1 ';
//if( gender != '' || status!= '' || region != '') dbQuery += ' WHERE'
if(gender != ''){
    dbQuery += 'AND `gender` = '+ db.escape(parseInt(gender));
}
if(status != ''){
    dbQuery += 'AND `status` = '+ db.escape(parseInt(status));
}
if(region != ''){
    dbQuery += 'AND `region` = '+ db.escape(parseInt(region));
}
dbQuery += ' LIMIT 10 OFFSET ' + db.escape(parseInt(offset));

db.query(dbQuery, queryInputs, function(err, result) {
    //code goes here
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as per best practices, if you want to fetch all the users, you may follow the approach given below:

1: Create a new API (/allUsers) with pagination obviously and create a separate SQL statement for this API, where you don't need to add a filter clause.

OR

2: Add a validation check in existing API, if there is no param then don't apply filters otherwise apply as usual.

Comment: Appreciate your help and time to answer here. However, I was trying to avoid writing multiple queries and get my desired output with a single query.

Comment: Single query would be very complex and passing param empty doesn't solve your problem